# Referenciar um grupo de ID's resultante de 'group_concat'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

Tenho um select que me retorna as linhas igualmente repetidas, junto com o total. Eu preciso referenciar esse grupo de ID's para passar como argumento.

O resultado da minha consulta é o array abaixo. Basicamente ele conta quantas linhas tem *Papa Charlie* no *text*, e com `group_concat` me informa is ID's.

```
Array(
    [0] => array(
            [count] => 3
            [text ] => Papa Charlie
            [ids  ] => 1,2,3
        )

)
```

É justamente esse grupo de ID's (1,2,3) que vai sofrer uma ação. Eu não queria ter que passar os ID's explicitamente como por exemplo `submit.php?id=1,2,3`.

Pensei em criar um `hash` para o campo *text* como argumento `md5(text)`, mas não sei se seria a melhor opção. Seria algo como `submit.php?hash=0f0b429bf93c7ee9696ae9541a02c10e`.

Qual seria a forma mais viável de se referenciar esse grupo?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você esta fazendo uma requisição GET (via url) para passar os parâmetros, dessa forma seus parâmetros vão ficar explicitos, fazer um rash realmente não é a melhor solução. Para parâmetros que você deseja ocultar ou são sensíveis você deve fazer uma requisição POST. Serializar estes parâmestros e passar via POST seria uma forma interessante. Algus links que podem te ajudar: http://www.diegomacedo.com.br/entendendo-a-diferenca-entre-os-metodos-get-e-post-no-php/ http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/462266-resolvidojson-com-php/

Comment: você pode explicar qual ação será executada em `submit.php`?